# Is it possible to restore an element to it's previous position without passing the position as a parameter?

Tags: javascript

The following function takes an `options` parameter and animates the element to a particular `amount` of pixels based on a `startValue`:

```
options: {
  property: 'right',
  startValue: '-250px',
  amount: '250px'
},

function (options) {
  const $el = $(this.el)
  $el.click(() => {
    const startValue = $el.parent().css(slide.property)
    const calcValue = parseInt(startValue, 10) + parseInt(slide.amount, 10)
    if (startValue === slide.startValue) {
      $el.parent().animate({ [slide.property]: calcValue }, 200)
    } else {
      $el.parent().animate({ [slide.property]: slide.startValue }, 200)
    }
  })
 }
```

But I'm wondering, is it possible to accomplish the same without having to provide the `startValue` to the function? (e.g if the initial value of `right` was `0` then restore it to `0` the second time you click the element.)

Comment: What do you mean by restore to previous position?

Comment: @snookieordie I clarified that in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that `.animate()` is adding an inline style attribute when it is called. So if you want to restore an element back to the `right` value specified in your CSS, you can call `.removeAttr("style")`. To get the animated effect, you would have to include a transition property in your CSS.

For example, check out this working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hr0cxax2/1/

```
$("#slideButton").on("click", function() {
    $("div").animate({right:"-=50px"}, 200);
});

$("#restoreButton").on("click", function() {
    $("div").removeAttr("style");
});
```

---

```
div {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    top: 20px;
    right: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    position: fixed;
    -webkit-transition: right 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: right 0.2s;
    transition: right 0.2s;
}
```

Otherwise, as far as I know, you would need to get and save the original `right` value before `.animate()` is called.